# Internet connection for app in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to hit a server using an android app which I developed. Though I'm able to access different web sites using android browser present in emulator, my app is not hitting the server.

This is code to check availability of internet:

```
ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

if(mWifi.isConnected()){
}
else{

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check internet connection!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        LinearLayout toastLayout = (LinearLayout) toast.getView();
        TextView toastTV = (TextView) toastLayout.getChildAt(0);
        toastTV.setTextSize(30);
        toast.show();
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    }
```

Toast present in else block is being showed.

These are permissions requested in `androidmanifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

This app works fine on real device, but I'm unable to test with emulator. Please throw some light.

There are no proxy settings being used in my network.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using only wifi method, that is the problem. because technically your emulator is not connectd to wifi, its your computer. try every other method. and it will get connected.

try this link. good example -http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/